# How i run the test with rspec, using simple_token_authentication and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, device, rspec-rails

I run my test but the sign_in don't authenticate.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "get all contacts route", :type => :request do
    let!(:contacts) {FactoryBot.create_list(:random_contacts, 20)}

    before(:each) do 
        get '/api/v1/contacts'
        user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
        
        request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
        request.headers['X-User-Email'] = "#{user.email}"
        request.headers['X-User-Token'] = "#{user.authentication_token}"
        sign_in user
    end

    it 'returns all contacts' do
        expect(JSON.parse(response.body).size).to eq(20)
    end
    it 'returns status code 200' do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
end
```

The return of the test is:

```
"{\"error\":\"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.\"}"
```

https://github.com/andbri321/one_bit_contacts/tree/feature/test_contact

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create some sign in/out helpers. Something along the lines of

```
module DeviseRequestSpecHelpers

  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  def sign_in(resource_or_scope, resource = nil)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    login_as(resource, scope: scope)
  end

  def sign_out(resource_or_scope)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    logout(scope)
  end

end
```

And then load them in your RSpec config like so:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include DeviseRequestSpecHelpers, type: :request
end
```

Then use these helpers before the tests are run.

[Look here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/37161-rspec-devise-how-to-sign-in-users-in-request-specs) for more info.